# Adaptive placeholder and bootstrap input-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, placeholder

I am trying to use the adaptive placeholder CSS files on my page - it works perfectly for text and select inputs but when I try and use it with bootstraps input-group, it just doesn't work.

I've created a bootply to show what I mean [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/mKnHggdAPB#) (the middle one is what I want it to look like)
[image]

This is the input-group that doesn't take the adaptive placeholder

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="divSupplierInput2" class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Text2" name="txtSupplier" value="" runat="server"
                required="">
            <label for="txtSupplier" placeholder="Supplier">
            </label>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button">
                    ...</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is an input where it does work

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input id="Text1" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" runat="server" required="">
    <label for="txtInvoiceNumber" placeholder="Invoice Number">
    </label>
</div>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use two divs, **col-sm-5  adjust-span-left** and **col-sm-1 adjust-span-right**.
You can also use col-sm-6 to col-sm-11 depending how long you want it to be.
Note I added *adjust-span-left* and *adjust-span-right* to the divs respectively, now use CSS to adjust it accordingly:

```
.adjust-span-right{
  margin-left: -40px;
}
/* To make it responsive to smaller screens add this */
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  .adjust-span-left{
  float:left;
  width:90%;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  .adjust-span-right{
  float:left;
  width:10%;
  overflow:hidden;
  } 
}
```

Then use this input

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5 adjust-span-left">
    <input id="txtInvoiceNumber" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" runat="server" required="">
    <label for="txtInvoiceNumber" placeholder="Invoice Number">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 adjust-span-right">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button">
            ...
        </button>
    </span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I noticed the placeholder doesn't show on the smaller screen on focus, so you should also adjust the css for that in the responsive css style.

Something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
 input[type="text"][required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
 input[type="text"][required]:valid + label[placeholder]:before {
   /* Adjust the css accordingly */
  -webkit-transform: translate(6px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(6px, -10px);
  transform: translate(8px, -10px);
 }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work - did you see I am asking specifically about how to get this to work using the adaptive placeholder? If you use the bootply link above and click in to the Invoice Number text box, you will see the placeholder moves, that is what I am trying to achieve with the input group

Comment: @leddy Your question was not clear to me. What i saw was you were trying to achieve what you showed in the second image and that is what i had given you. If that wasn't the case you could have just pointed that out in your comment rather than try to become a critic, there was no need for a down vote. Anyway see my updated answer if that helps you. Thanks.

Comment: I apologise @Laiman, I know you are only trying to help me and i do appreciate it. Your edit certainly gets me closer but unfortunately it doesn't work when you resize the screen, the button gets put underneath the input, whereas with the input-group it doesn't - image here to show what I mean https://i.imgur.com/JIH7a1q.png - thanks again for your help

Comment: @leddy Tha's alright. See my updated answer. I use media queries to detect screen width and then adjust the two divs accordingly. See if that is working for you?